# Unable to align checkbox while using angular materal

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, angular-material, display

```
    <div class="checkbox-password">
        <div>
           <mat-checkbox class="example-margin">Remember me</mat-checkbox>
        </div>
        <div>
           <a routerLink="/forgotPassword" class="createAccount" 
                    routerLinkActive="active"> Forgot Password? </a>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Using the above code I get remember me and forgotPassword next to each other, I need help in giving space between them, I have tried the following CSS code. Thanks in advance.

CSS:

```
.checkbox-password {
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a class to the div, and applying the styles to the div.

For example:

```
<div class="checkbox-password">
    <div class="remember-me">
       <mat-checkbox class="example-margin">Remember me</mat-checkbox>
    </div>
    <div>
       <a routerLink="/forgotPassword" class="createAccount" 
                routerLinkActive="active"> Forgot Password? </a>
   </div>
```

And in the css

```
.remember-me {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```